# Adjsut the unix timestamp to be the same on Yahoo Finance

Tags: excel, vba, yahoo-finance

In Sheet1, I have ticker in B1 (say "AA") and start date in B2 (say 21/4/2009) and the end date in B3 (say 23/4/2009)

When navigating manually to the desired url I got the link like that
https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AA/history?period1=1240290000&period2=1240462800&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d

But when using the code so as to construct the link I got little different UNIX timestamp like this
https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AA/history?period1=1240272000&period2=1240444800&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d

Notice period1 for example in both links
How can I adjust the code so as to be the same as the link at yahoo?

I tried something like that

```
period1 = ToUnix(.Range("B2").Value & " 05:00:00")
```

This solved the problem of those dates but doesn't solve other and different dates so my logic is not correct

Here's the code I tried

```
Sub Yahoo_Finance()
Dim ws          As Worksheet
Dim sURL        As String
Dim sTicker     As String
Dim period1     As Long
Dim period2     As Long
Dim r           As Long

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
r = 6

With CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    With ws
        sTicker = .Range("B1").Value
        period1 = ToUnix(.Range("B2").Value & " 05:00:00")
        period2 = ToUnix(.Range("B3").Value & " 05:00:00")
    End With

    sURL = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/" & sTicker & "/history?period1=" & period1 & "&period2=" & period2 & "&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d"

    Debug.Print sURL
End With
End Sub

Public Function ToUnix(dt) As Long
ToUnix = DateDiff("s", "1/1/1970", dt)
End Function
```

Comment: I'm confused. Are you saying that in the above you now get matching urls using your ToUnix function but there is a problem with other url constructions?

Comment: If you omit the part " 05:00:00", you will get different urls. I mean I need to get the same url as in the browser when using filter by dates. Try other old dates and notice the url on the browser and the url constructed in my code without this part " 05:00:00"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I observe it runs from 11pm the night before specified date for Start to 11pm night before date for End. So, `DateAdd` -1 day in code to remove 1 day from dates in sheets and ensure the hour is at `23:00:00`. Then the urls match for me.

```
Public Sub Yahoo_Finance()
    Dim ws          As Worksheet
    Dim sURL        As String
    Dim sTicker     As String
    Dim period1     As Long
    Dim period2     As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
        With ws
            sTicker = .Range("B1").Value
            period1 = ToUnix(DateAdd("d", -1, .Range("B2").Value) & "23:00:00")
            period2 = ToUnix(DateAdd("d", -1, .Range("B3").Value) & "23:00:00")
        End With

        sURL = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/" & sTicker & "/history?period1=" & period1 & "&period2=" & period2 & "&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d"

        Debug.Print sURL
    End With
End Sub
```

---

For GMT local time conversions you could try the code by [Rick Rothstein](http://www.excelfox.com/forum/showthread.php/542-Get-standard-GMT-time-from-the-system-using-vba)

```
Function Local2GMT(dtLocalDate As Date) As Date
    Local2GMT = DateAdd("s", -GetLocalToGMTDifference(), dtLocalDate)
End Function

Function GMT2Local(gmtTime As Date) As Date
    GMT2Local = DateAdd("s", GetLocalToGMTDifference(), gmtTime)
End Function

Function GetLocalToGMTDifference() As Long
    Const TIME_ZONE_ID_INVALID& = &HFFFFFFFF
    Const TIME_ZONE_ID_STANDARD& = 1
    Const TIME_ZONE_ID_UNKNOWN& = 0
    Const TIME_ZONE_ID_DAYLIGHT& = 2
    Dim TimeZoneInf As TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION
    Dim Ret As Long
    Dim Diff As Long
    Ret = GetTimeZoneInformation(TimeZoneInf)
    Diff = -TimeZoneInf.Bias * 60
    GetLocalToGMTDifference = Diff
    If Ret = TIME_ZONE_ID_DAYLIGHT& Then
        If TimeZoneInf.DaylightDate.wMonth <> 0 Then
            GetLocalToGMTDifference = Diff - TimeZoneInf.DaylightBias * 60
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

E.g. (per OP feedback.. no DateAdd adjustment required and )

```
period1 = ToUnix(Local2GMT(.Range("B2").Value))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have navigate and searched for the AA between 1 March 2012 and 5 March 2012 and copy the link to a text file `https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AA/history?period1=1330552800&period2=1330898400&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d` then run the code after changing the dates in B2 and B3 and got the url `https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AA/history?period1=1330513200&period2=1330858800&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d`. They are still different as you see

Comment: I think it is related to GMT time as I have changed 23:00:00 to 11:00:00 م  but this doesn't work too. And when I tried `period1 = ToUnix(DateAdd("d", -1, .Range("B2").Value) & " 10:00:00 م")` it worked fine and I tried with several dates with that format and is fine. Is there a way to adjust according the difference in time between local time and the GMT time?

Comment: Not sure how you are seeing the site as the above code works perfectly for me with no adjustment. I am using GMT so I guess you may need a conversion.

Comment: you could try this: http://www.excelfox.com/forum/showthread.php/542-Get-standard-GMT-time-from-the-system-using-vba  I assumed the site is expecting GMT but haven't verified.

Comment: That's perfect. I used the code on the excelfox link and it works very well for me when trying `period1 = ToUnix(Local2GMT(.Range("B2").Value))`. Thanks a lot for great help.

Comment: No dateadd adjustment? Or did you adjust in sheet?

Comment: No the same date in the sheet is the same. I just used the UDF Local2GMT and it does work fine.

Comment: And are you using 23:00?

Comment: No in my system I am using 12 Hour Clock System

Comment: weird. Server side it must do the appropriate changes anyway. Does it make difference what time you add on?

Comment: I don't know in fact. But as for me this approach succeeds in several different dates and adjusted the desired URLs in both the browser and the code